# jQuery - Can you over every pair of html elements? Like every <h3></h3><div></div>?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery accordian that I would like to loop to grab the data from them.

The format is:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<div><textarea>Description</textarea></div>
```

Can I loop over each pair so I can grab the Name and Description? I would rather not wrap them in another div if I don't have to.

Thanks.

Comment: What's with the dots?

Comment: So you can see the html. Does SO display html as text?

Comment: RTFM: [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

Comment: @Smith - as long as you mark it up as a code-block

Comment: OK, thank everyone for the quick replies. I'm still getting used to jScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("h3").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text()); <--- Your title text
    console.log($(this).next("div").children("textarea").text()); <--- description
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bC5Mk/

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
var things = $('h3').map(function(){ return {
    name: $(this).text(),
    description: $(this).next('div').find('textarea').val()
}}).get();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ixonag/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code if your structure is always `h3` and then a `div`,

```
var items = [];
$('h3').each (function () {
   items.push({
               'Name': $(this).text(), 
               'Description' : $(this).next().text()
              });
})
```